# Grab contents of a Wikipedia article

Tags: php, api, wikipedia

I want to get the contents of a wikipedia article using the actual API. Now, I know full well about `action=render` and `action=raw`, but I want the most barebones version possible, in plain text. No formatting, no links, preferably no templates, no citations, and no TOC. To give an example, here's an excerpt from the SO page:

```
<p><b>Stack Overflow</b> is a <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website" title="Website">website</a>, part of the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange_Network" title="Stack Exchange Network">Stack Exchange Network</a>,<sup id="cite_ref-blog_legal_1-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-blog_legal-1"><span>[</span>2<span>]</span></a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-stackapps_legal_2-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-stackapps_legal-2"><span>[</span>3<span>]</span></a></sup> featuring questions and answers on a wide range of topics in <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming" title="Computer programming">computer programming</a>.<sup id="cite_ref-secrets_3-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-secrets-3"><span>[</span>4<span>]</span></a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-slashdot_4-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-slashdot-4"><span>[</span>5<span>]</span></a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-google-tech-talks_5-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-google-tech-talks-5"><span>[</span>6<span>]</span></a></sup></p>
```

This is after all the templates and stuff even. I want to cut those out completely, and find where the real article starts. Then I need to shave this down further to something like:

> Stack Overflow is a website, part of
>   the Stack Exchange Network, featuring
>   questions and answers on a wide range
>   of topics in computer programming.

How can I cut through the templating and wiki formatting to get the raw article contents by themselves? This'd be implemented in PHP.

Comment: Probably it's written in the docs: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Comment: @hakre Doesn't seem like it, unless I missed it?

Answer (score 1):

The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) and [mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) api has everything you are looking for. For the SO example, here is the [SO wiki api page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Stack%20Overflow&rvprop=content).

I don't think you can get plain text directly through the API though. You need to choose from these [set of parsers](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) for what you are looking for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: None of those seem to really do what I am looking for :/

Comment: Well, you don't always get a cut and try ready made solution. You need to start someplace and work from there.

Comment: But none of those do anything better than the API itself, which is pretty far off from my goal.

Comment: Were you looking for something like this - http://icodesnip.com/snippet/php/php-bot-to-get-wikipedia-definitions

Comment: It gives me an error when I try to use it unfortunately: http://codepad.viper-7.com/O1Job8

Comment: Looks like there was a problem with the URL. Try this - http://codepad.viper-7.com/Xr1NAR